# display 'add content' form in tpl file

Tags: forms, drupal-7, content-type

i am new in drupal.
i want to have a slider with a 'add a content' form (form to add story under content type 'Story') loaded in it.
i have no idea how to create it inside the slider.

I am not having template.php in my theme folder.
is it possible call the form in tpl file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [drupal_get_form](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/drupal_get_form/7) function to load the node form for your content type.  although ideally you would not want to do this in a .tpl file, and instead do it in a custom module that creates a block, with that form in it.

Example for your .tpl

```
<?php

    global $user;
    module_load_include('inc','node','node.pages');
    $node_form = drupal_get_form('story_node_form',array('uid'=>$user->uid,'type'=>'story'));
    echo render($node_form);
```